# adding WMS service to application ArcGIS JS api

Tags: arcgis-server, coordinate-system, javascript

I've got map in projection: 4326 (WGS-84) when I try to add WMS layers which is in different projection I always get `connection timeout` Do you know if I could change WMS projection to set it up compatible with my projection? When I was using JAVA sdk I could connect WMS in different projections and arcgis server changed it projection ad hoc.